# pod trunk push fail, when build xcodebuild in i386

Tags: cocoapods

My pod version

`pod --version
1.2.0.beta.1`

I try to push  my sdk to cocoapods

`pod trunk push --use-libraries --allow-warnings --verbose`

And there are my podspec.json

```
{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "summary": "",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "7.0"
  },
  "requires_arc": true,
  "frameworks": [
    "Foundation",
    "CoreGraphics",
    "UIKit",
    "CoreTelephony",
    "AudioToolbox",
    "SystemConfiguration",
    "CoreFoundation",
    "CFNetwork",
    "AVFoundation",
    "CoreAudio",
    "Security",
    "CoreLocation"
  ],
  "libraries": [
    "sqlite3.0",
    "z",
    "resolv"
  ],
}
```

But it fail when Building with xcodebuild, I get the error

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld /Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App normal x86_64
    cd /var/folders/pt/bs9qqr3518vfqns9p6wkf9_h0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin:/Users/****/.pyenv/shims:/Users/****/.pyenv/bin:/Users/****/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.1.sdk -L/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -L/var/folders/pt/bs9qqr3518vfqns9p6wkf9_h0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/JCore -F/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/var/folders/pt/bs9qqr3518vfqns9p6wkf9_h0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/JMessage -filelist /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App_lto.o -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ljcore-ios-1.1.0 -lresolv -lsqlite3.0 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework Foundation -framework JMessage -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework UserNotifications -framework Foundation -lPods-App -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gyxbdimplseshvgwiyzdpehcncag/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App

** BUILD FAILED **
```

because my SDK don't support to i386. so it will fail in i386.

Are there any way to ignore the error, I just don't want to support to i386

Answer (score 0):

Because my dependence lib's Architectures are are: armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64

but my lib contain Architectures are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64

so It will build in i386 when pod trunk push.

To fix this error, add this code in .podspect file

```
s.xcconfig = {
'VALID_ARCHS' =>  'arm64 x86_64',
}
```

Comment: could you describe more specific how you were doing to fix this error, please?

Comment: @stanliu [goto this link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html) and download the test project use this command line `pod lib create MyLibrary`, and add you lib to this test project, you will get the error, if you fix this error, you can push you lib to cocoapad.

Comment: I know. But I mean you said you remove i386 from your lib. Could you describe it how to do that? Thanks!!!

Comment: lipo youlib.a -remove i386 -output outputlib.a